# Are there Adobe hosted rsls for the 3.4 sdk?

Tags: apache-flex, rsl

I know that starting with 4.0, Adobe is hosting framework rsls.  Are the 3.4 framework rsls hosted anywhere?  If not, does anyone know if there is a plan to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You have to host your own.